# Is there any reason why using an NSMutableDictionary would crash NSNotificationCenter?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsnotifications, nsnotificationcenter

When posting notifications with NSNotificationCenter, is there any reason why passing in a NSMutableDictionary instead of an NSDictionary as the userInfo could cause a crash?

```
- (void)postNotificationName:(NSString *)aName object:(id)anObject userInfo:(NSDictionary *)aUserInfo;
```

I'm seeing the following crash log:

```
 Exception Type:  SIGSEGV
 Exception Codes: SEGV_ACCERR at 0xffffffffe0000008
0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x31516fbc objc_msgSend + 16
1   Foundation                          0x3195b50f __57-[NSNotificationCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:]_block_invoke_0 + 19
2   CoreFoundation                      0x37a02577 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke_0 + 71
3   CoreFoundation                      0x3798e0cf _CFXNotificationPost + 1407
4   Foundation                          0x318cf3fb -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 67
```

Comment: is there any other information in the crash log (like, for example... what kind of crash is it? is there an exception being thrown, etc.)?

Comment: Are you sure that the NSMutableDictionary instance is valid (i.e. has not been released), and also the data inside it is valid? Do you see a crash when you pass `nil` for the last parameter?

Comment: My bet: runtime sends a message to an released object. Please check if you don't release something too early.

Comment: It shouldn't I just tried it and no problems. Maybe it's on the receiving end. Can you post your @(selector) method on receiving.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that your observer is crashing the app. Did you remove it from observer list before dealloc ?

Comment: Yep, odds are the notifyee has gone bye-bye.